# BOOST_STATIC_WARNING in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I wish to include Boost into my Xcode project as per the example in *[Serialization - Tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html)*.

I am using Boost version "1_60".

The project I am using is built using CMake.

```
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization system filesystem iostreams unit_test_framework date_time )
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

target_include_directories(serialExample PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
```

When I use the following includes...

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
```

> "Unused typedef 'STATIC_WARNING_LINE102'"
>
> "Unused typedef 'STATIC_WARNING_LINE98'"
>
> "Unused typedef 'STATIC_WARNING_LINE137'"
>
> "Unused typedef 'STATIC_WARNING_LINE148'"

This highlights four issues in two files which appear to be inside of the includes files.

extended_type_info_typeid.hpp

check.hpp

The code inspector goes to the error....

```
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:38:
/opt/local/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:102:9: error: unused typedef 'STATIC_WARNING_LINE102' [-Werror,-Wunused-local-typedef]
        BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(boost::is_polymorphic< T >::value);
        ^
```

Is there a way to stop this? How do I suppress this type of warning?

Is this a Clang issue? Isn't Boost cross-platform?

Answer (score 0):

Boost is error-free, but it does not purport itself as warning free. You are getting errors, because you told the compiler to treat warnings as errors (`-Werror`).

If you don't want to see Boost warnings, you can make sure that the compiler path to the headers is given by `-isystem` rather than `-I`, which will hide warnings from those headers. In CMake, this can be done by including the SYSTEM option in `include_directories`. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html.

Comment: Ok. I've changed it to 
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) and rebuilt. However, the error persists. Do i need link_directories AND  target_include_directories?

Comment: What version of cmake are you using? For old versions you might need to add `set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_CXX "-isystem ")` before you use `include_directories`, although I'm pretty sure that bug was only for GCC.

Comment: Hmmm. Sadly not. I've included it and rebuilt, but still, Xcode is throwing this error when i try to build. I've also tried to turn off unused variables etc in project settings. A bit of a head scratcher.

Comment: What command is being used to compile (i.e., what is XCode doing)?

Comment: I don't know. This is supposed to be an executable target as part of a larger set of code. There's so much cmake, it's not easy to navigate. This error also occurs if i don't reference boost at all in cmake. So clearly, i'm doing it completely wrong.